# tcomb - validation error message custom formatting

Tags: tcomb

Currently I have a `t.Number` field.

When I call `t.validate()` on it, it gives me the following `result.errors`:

```
{
    "actual": "James King", 
    "message": "Invalid value \"James King\" supplied to /user_id: Number",
    "path": ["user_id"]
}
```

Is it possible to modify the output of the `t.Number` validation to have:

```
{
    "actual": "James King", 
    "message": "Oops! The value is invalid", 
    "path": ["user_id"]
}
```

Also, am I getting that `results.errors` because I am in `NODE_ENV` "development"? If so, what results.errors will I get if I am in "production"?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in the end.

As per: https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-validation#customise-error-messages

Attach a getValidationErrorMessage() function to the 'type'.
i.e.

```
Number.getValidationErrorMessage = (value, path, context) => {
  return '"'+value+'" is invalid. It must be a number.';
}
```

Then made the call to tcomb-validate's validate():

`const result = t.validate('s', Number);`

It gave the result with the customized error message:

```
result Struct {
  errors: 
   [ Struct {
       message: '"s" is invalid. It must be a number.',
       actual: 's',
       expected: [Object],
       path: [] } ],
  value: 's' }
```